# How to quickly learn Python and Ruby frameworks coming from a PHP background

Tags: kohana, pylons, sinatra, ramaze

I've been using CakaPHP and Kohanaphp but now I want to try out other frameworks from a more sophisticated OOP language for my next projects.

How can I learn the following frameworks quickly so I can immediately pick what to use:

- Pylons
- Sinatra
- Ramaze

Tutorials and examples from online resources would really be great.

For php developers who've already underwent this learning experience, please share yours.

Thanks

Comment: You need to accept answers to your previous questions. People wont be inclined to help otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Pylons. There is a good introductory book written by one of the creators of Pylons. It is freely available online at http://pylonsbook.com/

Answer (score 0):

For Ramaze, see:

- [the website](http://ramaze.net/)
- [the wiki](http://wiki.ramaze.net/Home)
- [the book](http://book.ramaze.net/)
- [the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/ramaze)
- [the IRC channel](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=ramaze)

Answer (score 0):

You can also learn about setting up Sinatra with Google's App Engine (via jRuby) here: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/

Fairly quick and easy setup.

There's also this screencast at PeepCode https://peepcode.com/products/sinatra